# Add legend to sns.regplot and sns.lmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am new at seaborn and want to add a legend to this plot, I found unfortunalty nothing in this way.

```
sns.lmplot(x="x", y="y4", data=data, order=2, scatter_kws={"s":5}, line_kws={"color": "red"}, ci=95)
sns.regplot(x="x", y="y4", data=data, scatter_kws={"s":5}, line_kws={"color": "green"}, )
plt.show();
```

[image]

I want following as a legend:
blue points as `data`, 
green line as `y`, 
red line as `y^`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you generated the scatter plot. Probably using `plt.scatter`. But here is how you can change the legend for the `lmplot` and `regplot` as

```
l = sns.lmplot(x="x", y="y4", data=data, order=2, scatter_kws={"s":5}, line_kws={"color": "red"}, ci=95)
r = sns.regplot(x="x", y="y4", data=data, scatter_kws={"s":5}, line_kws={"color": "green"}, )

labels = ['y^', 'y']

l._legend.texts[0].set_text(labels[0])
r._legend.texts[0].set_text(labels[1])
```

Here, `l` and `r` return the plot instance and then you use the `_legend` to access the respective legends and `set_text` to rename the text of your choice.

Comment: Doesn't work any longer (at least not with seaborn 0.11.1): `r._legend` doesn't exist. The alternative candidates, `r.legend` and `r.legend_` don't have `.texts`.